# Magento 2 404 saving CMS page/block after moving to new server

Tags: magento2

Just as the title says, after moving my install over to a server I get 404 when saving a page or block.   I cleared cache and re-compiled.

Any ideas?  Nothing in logs with errors.

Versions is 2.1.2

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5008

Comment: My store is already not a single store, theres multiple.  Which seems to be the fix there.   I have taken the steps to try and resolve based on that thread with no result, though.